# Rails how to run a method when a record is three months old?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

Basically what i want to do is to delete a file and a record (which contains the file path) when the record is three months old, the file is uploaded through Carrierwave.

This is kinda what i have in mind for deleting the record and file.

```
 # Code for deleteing PDF files (receipts) every 90 days
  def auto_delete_receipts
    #get user id from params or as a method parameter
    user = params[:id]

    user.receipts.each do |receipt|
      #check if receipt is three months old
        receipt.remove_receiptFile!
        receipt.save
      #end
    end
  end
```

so i would like to know where should i locate my method and how to automatically run it everytime a record gets three months old, in order to delete it.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: time-based tasks are typically done via cron, checkout the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: Usually you set up a `scope` that defines which records to affect.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking at it from the wrong angle. Rather than creating a single callback which would fire at three months from now you create a task which runs at a regular interval and prune records which are older than a certain age.

Doing it the other way around would not be very efficient since you need to keep track of when all those callbacks should be fired and you would have to do it on a per record basis.

The first step is to create a [rake task](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks):

```
namespace :things do
  desc "Removes records older than 3 months"
  task :prune => :environment do
    puts "Removing things older than 3 months"
    destroyed = Thing.where("created_at < ?", 3.months.ago).destroy_all
    puts "{destroyed.length} records deleted."
  end
end
```

The [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem as mentioned in the comments is a good way to schedule this if you are deploying to a server which supports cron. On Heroku you can use the [Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) instead which is a addon.

Comment: Note that `destroy_all` issues a `DELETE FROM Things WHERE Thing.created_at < ?` SQL statement. This deletes all the records in one query. Iterating though all the records with each could cause the memory in your server to become exhausted and is much slower.

Answer (score 3):

Your on the right track, I'd recommend creating a script that successfully identified and deleted the PDFs that were 90+ days old. Then you could utilize cron to run the script every day.

Your example uses the method `each` - which is really mostly for arrays, you'd do best to use a rake task like the answer @max suggested - you can read more here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/Task.html

To learn about `cron` you can read more here: I don't know the server you're using, but assuming it's a linux instance, here's a helpful guide from Amazon: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-cron.html